# my edit function is not working where are my going wrong?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make an edit function for my project but it's not working, it is only updating five of my variables that are in another table but the rest of them aren't updating - it only updates the variables in my custom user model which are `first_name`, `last_name`, `username` and `email` - it doesn't update the variables in my admin model - where am I going wrong?
Any help will be appreciated - I am still new in Django so excuse any mistakes

this is my custom user model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data=((1,"Admin"),(2,"senioremployee"),(3,"employee"))
    user_type=models.CharField(default=1,choices=user_type_data,max_length=20)
```

this is my admin model

```
class admin(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Dob = models.DateField()
    Nationality = models.TextField()
    Address = models.TextField()
    Postcode = models.TextField()
    Telephone = models.TextField()
    Wage = models.TextField()
    Passportnumber = models.TextField()
    passportexpirydate = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    profile_pic = models.FileField()
    kinname = models.TextField()
    kinrelation = models.TextField()
    kinaddress = models.TextField()
    kinphonenumber = models.TextField()
    kinemail = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.FileField()
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

this is my edit function

```
def edit_admin_save(request):
    if request.method!="POST":
        return HttpResponse("<h2> Method Not Allowed </h2>")
    else:
        admin_id = request.POST.get("admin_id")
        first_name=request.POST.get("first_name")
        last_name=request.POST.get("last_name")
        username=request.POST.get("username")
        email=request.POST.get("email")
        Dob=request.POST.get("Dob")
        Nationality=request.POST.get("Nationality")
        Address=request.POST.get("Address")
        Postcode=request.POST.get("Postcode")
        Telephone=request.POST.get("Telephone")
        Wage=request.POST.get("Wage")
        Passportnumber=request.POST.get("Passportnumber")
        passportexpirydate=request.POST.get("passportexpirydate")
        gender=request.POST.get("gender")
        kinname=request.POST.get("kinname")
        kinrelation=request.POST.get("kinrelation")
        kinaddress=request.POST.get("kinaddress")
        kinphonenumber=request.POST.get("kinphonenumber")
        kinemail=request.POST.get("kinemail")
        
        if request.FILES.get('profile_pic',False):
            profile_pic=request.FILES['profile_pic']
            fs =FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(profile_pic.name,profile_pic)
            profile_pic_url = fs.url(filename)
        else:
            profile_pic_url = None
        
        
        try:
            user=CustomUser.objects.get(id = admin_id)
            user.first_name=first_name
            user.last_name=last_name
            user.email=email
            user.username=username
            user.save()
            admin_model=admin.objects.get(admin = admin_id)
            admin_model.Dob = Dob
            admin_model.Nationality = Nationality
            admin_model.Address = Address
            admin_model.Postcode = Postcode
            admin_model.Telephone = Telephone
            admin_model.Wage = Wage
            admin_model.Passportnumber = Passportnumber
            admin_model.passportexpirydate = passportexpirydate
            admin_model.gender = gender
            admin_model.kinname = kinname
            admin_model.kinrelation = kinrelation
            admin_model.kinaddress = kinaddress
            admin_model.kinphonenumber = kinphonenumber
            admin_model.kinemail = kinemail
            if profile_pic_url!=None:
                admin_model.profile_pic = profile_pic_url
            admin_model.save()
            messages.success(request, "Successfully Edited Admin")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/edit_admin/"+admin_id)
        except:
            messages.error(request, "Couldnt Edit Admin")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/edit_admin/"+admin_id)
```

Edit this my form for my admin class

```
class EditAdminForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label = "Username",max_length = 50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label = "First Name",max_length = 50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label = "Last Name",max_length = 50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email", max_length = 50, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}))
    Dob = forms.DateField(label = "Date of Birth", widget = DateInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    Nationality = forms.CharField(label = "Nationality",max_length = 50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    Address = forms.CharField(label = "Address",max_length = 50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    Postcode = forms.CharField(label = "Postcode",max_length = 50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    Telephone = forms.CharField(label = "Telephone",max_length = 50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    Wage = forms.CharField(label = "Wage",max_length = 50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    Passportnumber = forms.CharField(label = "Passport Number",max_length = 50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    passportexpirydate = forms.DateField(label = "Passport Expiry Date", widget = DateInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    profile_pic = forms.FileField(label = "Profile Picture",widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),required=False)
    gender_choice = (
        ("Male","Male"),
        ("Female","Female")
    )
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(label = "Gender", choices=gender_choice,widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"form-control"}))
    kinname = forms.CharField(label = "Next of Kin name",max_length = 50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    kinrelation = forms.CharField(label = "Relation",max_length = 50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    kinaddress = forms.CharField(label = "Kinaddress",max_length = 50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    kinphonenumber = forms.CharField(label = "Kin Phonenumber",max_length = 50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
    kinemail = forms.EmailField(label = "Kin Email",max_length = 50, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs = {"class":"form-control"}))
```

Comment: why aren't you using [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/)?? (soo much pain :( )

Comment: try to use `except Exception as ex: return HttpResponse(ex)` and see what the error actually is

Comment: @SLDem it giving me the error - “” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format. what should i do

Comment: looks like theres an issue with your passport expiry field, can you show me your form?

Comment: @SLDem i have updated the my question you can see the form now

Comment: try handling your form using `form.save()` instead of manually grabbing the data using 20 `get`s

Comment: @SLDem i got the error -- CustomUser matching query does not exist.

Comment: because you dont have a `admin_id` field declared in your form class and I imagine in the template so when you're querying the `CustomUser` object the query it doesnt get any data therefore the error

Comment: @SLDem thank for your help how can i declare it in my form

Comment: in your `EditAdminForm` add a field like this: `admin_id = forms.IntegerField()`

Comment: @SLDem thank you it works

Comment: you can also create a `forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_admin=True)` and pass in the queryset of admins to manually pick an admin you wanna edit instead of typing the `pk`